# On click UISearchBar Application Crashesh

Tags: objective-c

I am implementing search bar and when i click on search bar i got the exception [NSBigMutableString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil argument what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: what you have written in `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` function?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i didn't write any method replacecharacterInRange:with:function

Comment: No one have answer of this question?

Comment: can you please show code for reference seems you having issue in its one of delegates and implementation of your textDidChange delegate if you had used it ?

Comment: No have not used that method. I have implemented texfieldshouldbeginediting and if i return NO for that method application is not getting crash and i have implemented categories on UITextfield will that effect on that?

Comment: Search View problem is solved that problem occurred because of i have implemented the category on textfield.

Answer (score 0):

That problem is occurred due to i have implemented the category on textfield.
If you are implementing the category on textfield or uiview such problem will occurred